# Validation in checkbox form in yii2

Tags: php, yii

I have two models in a form.
One model is a master, and one model is representated as junction table (model).

[image: Relation]

Desc :

```
request_table : $model,
link_req_tipe : $modelLinkReqTipe;
```

My goal is,

1. I save the $model, then I get the $model->id
2. I batch insert to link_req_item

   **id_request = $model->id** and **id_tipe = modelLinkReqTipe->id_tipe**

Here it is the php :

**_form.php** (just example, because a lot of many input form)

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'karyawan_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Karyawan::find()->all(), 'id', 'first_name'), ['prompt' => 'Select Karyawan'])
 ?>

<?= $form->field($modelLinkReqTipe, 'id_tipe')->checkBoxList(ArrayHelper::map(TipeRequest::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_tipe'));
 ?>
```

**RequestController**

```
if ($model->load($request->post()) && $modelLinkReqTipe->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
  $valid = $model->validate();
  $valid = $modelLinkReqTipe->validate() && $valid;  

  if ($valid) { ## Check validate : true
     $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
     try {
       if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
         foreach ($modelLinkReqTipe as $index => $modelLinkReqTipe ) {
              if ($flag === false) {
                 break;
              }

              $modelLinkReqTipe->id_request = $model->id;
              if (!($flag = $modelLinkReqTipe->save(false))) {
                  break;
              }
         }
       }

       if ($flag) {
         $transaction->commit();
       } else {
         $transaction->rollBack()
       }
     }
     catch (\Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
     }

     return [
       'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',   
       'title' => "Create new Request",
       'content' => '<h1 class="text-success">Success</h1>,
       'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::a('Create More', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
                ];

  }else{ ## Check validate : false
     return [
        'title' => "Create New Request",
        'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
             'model' => $model,
             'modelLinkReqTipe' => (empty($modelLinkReqTipe)) ? new LinkReqTipe() : $modelLinkReqTipe,
             'modelLinkReqItem' => (empty($modelLinkReqItem)) ? [new LinkReqItem] : $modelLinkReqItem,
                    ]),
        'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                ];
            }
```

Now, validation is in trouble,
it always return false in submit.
[image: false validation]
Please Advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to resolve this issue. I think the best way to make sure that `$modelLinkReqTipe`'s attribute `id_request` is not taken into account upon validation is to provide `validate()` function with array of attributes you want to validate: `validate(['id_tipe'])`